# dojo declare correct way

Tags: javascript, static, dojo, declare

file:  `dojo/dir1/utils/XmlJsonUtils.js`

```
// Author: Rajat Khandelwal

define([
    "dojo/_base/declare" // declare
    ], function(declare){
      return declare("dir1.utils.XmlJsonUtils",[],{
        parseXml : function (xml) {
                     var self=this;
                     var dom = null;
                     if (window.DOMParser) {
                       try { 
                         dom = (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(xml, "text/xml"); 
                       } 
                       catch (e) { dom = null; }
                     }
                     else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
                       try {
                         dom = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLDOM');
                         dom.async = false;
                         if (!dom.loadXML(xml)) // parse error ..

        window.alert(dom.parseError.reason + dom.parseError.srcText);
                       } 
                       catch (e) { dom = null; }
                     }
                     else
                       alert("cannot parse xml string!");
                     return dom;
                   },
                 xml2json  : function (xmldata)
                 {
                   var self=this;
                   if(xmldata.firstChild==null)
                   {
                     return {name:xmldata.nodeName+": (value null)", checked: true}
                   }
                   else if(xmldata.firstChild.nodeType==3)
                   {
                     return {name:xmldata.nodeName+": "+xmldata.firstChild.nodeValue, checked:true}
                   }
                   else
                   {
                     var mychildren=[];
                     var i=0;
                     var nochildren=xmldata.childElementCount
                       for(i=0;i<nochildren;i++)
                       {
                         var j=self.xml2json(xmldata.childNodes[i])
                           mychildren[i]=j
                       }
                     var ret= {name:xmldata.nodeName, children:mychildren, checked:true}
                     return ret
                   }
                 },

                 convert2arr : function (result,ctr,res_arr)
                 {
                   var self=this;
                   if(result[ctr].checked[0]==false)
                     return;
                   if(result[ctr].children==undefined)
                   {
                     var name=result[ctr]['name'][0];
                     var kv = name.split(': ');
                     if(kv[1]=="(value null)")
                       kv[1]="";
                     res_arr.push.apply(res_arr,["<",kv[0],">",kv[1],"</",kv[0],">"]);
                     return ctr+1;
                   }
                   else
                   {
                     var i=ctr;
                     var new_ctr=ctr;
                     var no_children=result[ctr].children.length;
                     res_arr.push.apply(res_arr,["<",result[ctr].name[0],">"])
                       for(i=0;i<no_children;i++)
                       {
                         new_ctr=self.convert2arr(result,result[ctr].children[i]._0,res_arr)
                       }
                     res_arr.push.apply(res_arr,["</",result[ctr].name[0],">"]);
                     return new_ctr;
                   }
                 },
                 convert2xml : function (result)
                 {
                   var arr=[]
                     self.convert2arr(result, 0, arr)
                     return arr.join('')
                 }
      })
    })
```

but when in the code I `require` the `dir1.utils.XmlJsonUtils`, it says `Uncaught Error: declare XmlJsonUtils: base class is not a callable constructor`. What is the correct way to declare some utility functions.

And those should be like static functions. I don't want to do `x=new XmlJsonUtils(); x.parseXml(..)`. I want to do `XmlJsonUtils.parseXml(..)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your class should not have to have the constructor method defined, dojo.declare is supposed to handle this.. However, doing so doesnt hurt, simply define a blank `constructor: function() { }`. I suspect youre facing some sort of bug.

The define is as should be, 'define' is used for the require-scope, when running  require(["my.module"]), its expected to have a `define` method, which returns the base class via `declare`.

file: `dojo/dir1/utils/XmlJsonUtils.js`:

```
define([
   // requirements
   "dojo/_base/declare", 
   "dir1/utils/Toolkit" // sample in-package dependency
   "./Toolkit"     // Same as Above
], function (declare) {
   // no slash separator, use dot with declare, 
   // use a reference and return on last line
   var Klass = declare(
   /// declaredClass: string, moduleUrl with dot-separater + filename /.js//
       "dir1.utils.XmlJsonUtils",
   /// base class: Array(mixins)
       [],
   /// class scope
       {
           _methodMeantToBePrivate: function() { },
           randomInstanceMethod: function() { }
       }
   ); // end declare


   // set any aliases, which you want to expose (statics)

   Klass.StaticCallable = function() {
       // careful with your scope access inhere
   }

   // return the declared class to 'define'
   return Klass;
}); // end define
```

This way (you must have a reference, either pulled in with require or getObject), you could use the `StaticCallable` function without initializing / constructing an instance of the module. AMD compliant syntax is like so:

```
require(["dir1/utils/XmlJsonUtils"], function(xmlUtils) {
   xmlUtils.StaticCallable();
});
```

or if previously required

```
var xmlUtils = dojo.getObject("dir1.utils.XmlJsonUtils")
xmlUtils.StaticCallable();
```

A specific example could be a versatile class like the following, where both instance and static access is possible. Base class defines 'tools', derived class defines the variables the 'tools' operate on - and if instantiated, the default topics can be subscribed - [ [MessageBusBase](https://github.com/mschr/oocms/blob/master/admin/include/_messagebus.js) | [MessageBus](https://github.com/mschr/oocms/blob/master/admin/include/messagebus.js) ]

Comment: can you elaborate more on `careful with your scope access in here`? for example, I am defining a recursive function so I have to reference itself.

Comment: That would be no problem, however you often have a widget initialize stuff once it is constructed.. This is not the case here, if youre setting a static function you should also access class-variables statically (whilst this context being 'forbidden'). Ive appended links to a sample of an old CMS i made on dojo a while back

Comment: so you are suggesting I call it as `Klass.parseXml`. But where I `require` it, I don't have `Klass` defined, so won't that be an error?

Comment: `require(["dojo/dir1/utils/XmlJsonUtils"], function(util) { util.parseXml() });` works.. `Klass` is Only an internal variable - within the define(function() { *scope* }). **see last two code blocks in answer** :D

Answer (score 0):

The issue: in your code.

```
return declare("dir1.utils.XmlJsonUtils",[],{
    parseXml : function (xml) {
```

Instead of `dir1.utils.XmlJsonUtils` use `dir1/utils/XmlJsonUtils`, i.e., use slashes instead of dots in your function declaration.