# AMD and Dojo 1.7 questions

Tags: dojo, amd

Simple question.

Does AMD DOJO implementation support these type of declarations?

1. text!./plain.html

   ```
   define(["../Widget","text!./plain.html"],
     function(Widget,plain){
     return new Widget({name:"mainApp",template:plain});
   });
   ```
2. Load non-modules, let's say underscore.js

   ```
   require(['dir/underscore.js'], function(){
    _.reduce ...
   });
   ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but the precise syntax is different to that used in the question.

- [The Dojo Loader](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/loader/) (1.7)

  - [Plugins](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/loader/amd.html#plugins)

    - [dojo/text](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/text.html#dojo-text)

The plugin for loading character data is `dojo/text`.

The extension should not be used when loading a JavaScript library and the location of the file is set via either a relative of the dojotoolkit base or a *packages*  location declaration in dojoConfig:

```
require(['underscore'], function( _ ){
 _.reduce ...
});
```

Configure the namespace in the Dojo configuration to avoid messy import paths - see `dojoConfig` in the loader documentation.

Also, consider using the [dojo/global](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/global.html) module and/or defining a Dojo module as a wrapper for Underscore.js:

```
//_.js
define(['dojo/global', 'underscore'], function(global){
  return global._
});
```

With the above consideration, you must have loaded the actual .js file manually. If in conjunction with the dojo/text plugin, one would create a wrapper which also loads the required JS and evaluates it, following could do the trick.

/var/www/dojo-release-1.7/ext_lib/_.js - this sample file is hierachially placed in a library namespace, alongside dojo, dijit, dojox

```
define(['dojo/global', 'dojo/text!./Underscore.js'], function(global, scriptContents){
  global.eval(scriptContents);
  return global._ // '_' is the evaluated reference from window['_']
  /** 
   * Alternatively, wrap even further to maintain a closure scope thus hiding _ from global
   *  - so adapt global.eval to simply eval
   *  - remove above return statement
   *  - return a dojo declared module with a getInstance simple method
  */
  function get_ () { return _ };
  var __Underscore = declare('ext_lib._', [/*mixins - none*/], {
        getInstance: get_
  });
  // practical 'static' reference too, callable by 'ext_lib.getInstance' without creating a 'new ext_lib._'
  __Underscore.getInstance = get_;
  return __Underscore;
});
```

A sample of defining [own modules using declare](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11329163/dojo-declare-correct-way/11329956#11329956) here
*Note: this code is untested; feel free to add corrections.*

Comment: note about the first require in this text; by only telling toplevel namespace to require - a proper declaration of package 'underscore' must be supplied, following 'Dojo’s package concept', meaning 'underscore' is a directory and it contains a package descriptor (see CommonJS)

Comment: It works for me (using your first approach). I tried using the AMD supported underscorejs fork as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8131265/loading-backbone-and-underscore-using-requirejs. It did not work right away for me so I settled for this approach. Was anyone able to load this AMD underscore fork with the Dojo AMD loader?