# How to assign a static array to an object in Dojo?

Tags: javascript, actionscript, dojo

```
define(["dojo/_base/declare"], function (declare) {
    // module:
    //      StyleNames
    // summary:
    //      Style element names.
    var StyleNames = declare(null, 
        {
            PROP1: "Style1",
            PROP2: "Style2"
        }
    );

    StyleNames.dataContexts = [
        StyleNames.PROP1,
        StyleNames.PROP2,
    ];

    return StyleNames;
});

var styleNames = new StyleNames();
console.log("PROP1 is defined as: ", styleNames.PROP1); // prints "Style1"
console.log("dataContexts is undefined: ", styleNames.dataContexts); // Error: styleNames.dataContexts is undefined
```

My setup was similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/11329956/1610451 but looking in the DOM, I can see that it is set to the constructor `styleNames.constructor.dataContexts` with undefined values.

Backstory: I'm porting ActionScript code to JavaScript and need to maintain existing interfaces. An example of the ActionScript code that I'm porting is:

```
public class StyleNames {
    public static const PROP1 : String = "Style1";
    public static const PROP2 : String = "Style2";

    public static const dataContexts : Array = [
        PROP1,
        PROP2
    ];

    public function StyleNames(){}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got it right in your declaration.  That is the most unambiguous way to define static variables in my opinion.  In your `console.log` code, you're just not referring to the `dataContexts` variable correctly.  It's a *static* variable, so it does not belong to any one instance.  You want to refer to it this way: `StyleNames.dataContexts`.

Edit: you've also got a possible syntax error in there.  Take out the second comma under the `StyleNames.dataContexts` declaration:

```
StyleNames.dataContexts = [
    StyleNames.PROP1,
    StyleNames.PROP2
];
```

Access the variable like this:

```
StyleNames.dataContexts
```

as opposed to `this.dataContexts` or `instanceRef.dataContexts`

Comment: Although the Trailing Comma of Death is truly to be feared, there are actually no modern browsers that choke on it, and IE7 or 8 "fixed" this deadly "bug". Still, it is better to be careful. But modern browsers don't care (nor does PHP, for example).

Comment: Good point, @JaredFarrish.  I knew I had been bitten by that before, but I couldn't recall which browsers would choke on that.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I left out that I had tried referencing it as a static ("StyleNames.dataContexts") but that gives an undefined error as well. I also tried creating an instance variable in a constructor but setting the values outside the declare. Removing the extra comma didn't help either :(

Comment: youre correct, and so is OP. In the declaration, a simple variable referenced by `eval(declaredClass).StaticName` is created this way. But there's no inheritance relation between an instance of said module and its 'static' contents.

Comment: Got it, thank you! The trick was to place the other vars as static (which is what they should have been anyways). I thought I had already tried that, but oh well that's what I get for working on the weekend. @phusick answer is correct, but this answer was right from the start.

Answer (score 0):

This is how it is done right in my way of thinking:

```
require(["dojo/_base/declare"], function(declare) {

    var StyleNames = declare(null, {

        constructor: function() {
            // a.k.a public function StyleNames(){}
        },

        // non-static properties and functions here

    });

    // static properties and functions
    StyleNames.PROP1 = "Style1";
    StyleNames.PROP2 = "Style2";

    StyleNames.dataContexts = [
        StyleNames.PROP1,
        StyleNames.PROP2
    ];

    console.log("PROP1: ", StyleNames.PROP1);
    console.log("dataContexts: ", StyleNames.dataContexts);

});​
```

See a working example at jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/phusick/6nfhJ/